# Java Threads - for two while loops

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I am a begginer and i went over tutorials for this but still dont know how exactly to implement this.

I have two while loops one in main() method and one in send() method both need to be executing at the same time how do i go about this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{   
    socket = new DatagramSocket(13373); // 69 Reserved for TFTP

    // Listen for incoming packets
    while(true) {
        // Do things
    }
}

private static void sendDATA() {
    while(true) {
        // Do things
    }
}
```

While loop in sendDATA works by reading 512 bytes from a file then sending them to client class. While loop in main method receives packets from client and updates a variable if variable is true then sendDATA reads next 512 bytes and sends them and so on but i cant work in two threads.

I have done this with one while loop and program works, well sort of it transfers all the packets but the last one. Client never gets the last packet.

Server:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{   
    socket = new DatagramSocket(13373); // 69 Reserved for TFTP

    // Listen for incoming packets
    while(true) {
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(incoming, incoming.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        clientip = packet.getAddress().toString().replace("/", "");
        clientport = packet.getPort();

        System.out.println(clientport);

        if(incoming[0] == 1 || incoming[0] == 2) {
            handleRequest(incoming);
        } 

    }
}

// sends DATA opcode = 3 : | opcode | block # | data |
private static void sendDATA() {

    try {
        ByteBuffer sDATA = ByteBuffer.allocate(514);

        byte[] tmp = new byte[512];
        DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(sDATA.array(), sDATA.array().length, InetAddress.getByName(clientip), clientport);
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE));

        int a;
        int block = 1; 

        while((a = fis.read(tmp,0,512)) != -1)
        {
            data.setLength(a);
            sDATA.put((byte)3);
            sDATA.put((byte)block);
            System.out.println(sDATA.array().length);
            sDATA.put(tmp);
            System.out.println(tmp.length);
            socket.send(data); 

            socket.setSoTimeout(60000);

            while(true) {
                DatagramPacket getack = new DatagramPacket(incoming, incoming.length);
                try {
                    socket.receive(getack);
                    if(incoming[0] == 4 && incoming[1] == block) {  
                        break;
                    } else if(incoming[0] == 4 && incoming[1] == block && tmp.length < 511) {
                        fis.close();
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                   socket.send(data);
                   continue;
                }

            }
            block++;
        }       
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(8571);

    // WRQ || RRQ
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int opcode = input.nextInt(); input.close();

    // Pripravi paketek
    outgoing = makeRequestPacket(opcode,"filename.txt","US-ASCII");

    // Odposlje pakete
    sendPacket(outgoing);

    // Streznik vrne ACK - opcode 4 ali ERROR - opcode 5
    // Pri ACK zacnemo posiljat DATA opcode 3 drugace prekinemo povezavo ob ERROR - opcode 5
    while(true) {
        DatagramPacket receiveResponse =  new DatagramPacket(incoming, incoming.length);
        clientSocket.receive(receiveResponse);

        // opcode 5 - ERROR
        if(incoming[0] == 5) {
            getError(incoming);
        } 
        else if(incoming[0] == 4 && incoming[1] == 0) { // opcode 4 - Prvi ACK
            System.out.print("opcode: (" + incoming[0] +") ACK received operation confirmed.");
            continue;
        } 
        else if(incoming[0] == 3) {
            System.out.println("Ah got a data packet.");
            File initfile = new File("filename2.txt");
            if(!initfile.exists()) {
                initfile.createNewFile();
            } 

            int block;
            FileOutputStream fio = new FileOutputStream(initfile);

            if(incoming.length > 511) {
                block = incoming[1];
                System.out.println("Will start to write.");

                for(int i = 2; i < incoming.length; i++) {
                    fio.write(incoming[i]);
                }
                ByteBuffer recack = ByteBuffer.allocate(514);
                recack.put((byte)4);
                recack.put((byte)block);
                System.out.println("If i came here and nothing happened something went horribly wrong.");

                DatagramPacket replyACK = new DatagramPacket(recack.array(), recack.array().length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"),13373);
                clientSocket.send(replyACK);
            } else if (incoming.length < 511) {
                System.out.println("Last chunk.");
                block = incoming[1];
                for(int j = 2; j < incoming.length; j++) {
                    if(incoming[j] != 0) {
                        fio.write(incoming[j]);
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                ByteBuffer recack = ByteBuffer.allocate(514);
                recack.put((byte)4);
                recack.put((byte)block);


                DatagramPacket replyACK = new DatagramPacket(recack.array(), recack.array().length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"),13373);
                clientSocket.send(replyACK);
                fio.close();
                clientSocket.close();
                break;
            }
            continue;

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: what is desired read/write speed to socket?

Comment: It can be done in one thread. Why do you want to do it in two threads? Is that requirement to do read from client and send to client in two separate threads?

Comment: If you need to run two independent while(true) loops at the same time, you have to use two threads.  I can't see any way round that one.

Comment: Exactly. While(true) is not needed. First read data from file. Then send data to client. Then read data from client. Then Set the variable. And then if variable is true, then repeat previous steps again.

Comment: I did it with one while loop but i wrote such a complex code i never received the last packet i debugged on and on to no succsses. It was pointed out to me that it would be much cleaner even tho not needed to use 2 Threads one for each loop but i dont really know how to do this even after going over the tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a blocking channel in order to synchronize communication between your processes:

```
SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
socketChannel.configureBlocking(true);
```

More info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html

Also, sockets are designed to send data between processes, if that's not the case your approach is wrong and you should change your design, i.e. call each loop in a new thread when (or every time) data is ready for it (each thread will process its data and then die) or just execute both blocks of instructions sequentially inside one loop if you don't need concurrent execution. A state diagram of your program can help you determine which is the best solution.

Comment: That's a solution but are really two threads needed in this case ?

Comment: I wrote my code in one loop but i kept loosing the last packet after hours of debugging trying to make it work i asked for help and was suggested to use Threads even tho its not needed it would simplify the code at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

So what i have been looking for was a simple 'crude' way of runing two methods of the same class at the same time for instace two independant loops. Anyhow here is the code:

```
    class MyClass extends Thread {

public void run() {     // start new thread
    otherMethod();      // will calls another method
}
void otherMethod() {
     ....  executed in another Thread
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   MyClass mc = new MyClass();
   mc.start();                 // start other Thread
   ... continue in main() with actual thread
   ...
}
}
```